# How to clear the parent css

Tags: css

Say you had a Css style defined below .

```
div
{
    background: url(themes/default/images/backgrounds/lh-navigation.png) repeat-x;
}
.child
{
    backgroud-color:#FFFFFF;
}

<Div id="tempDiv" class="child"></Div>
```

I don't want the backgroud style applied to element tempDiv. How can i remove the parent style for the a specified div element. Is there any way to make it ?thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try:

```
.child#tempDiv{
   background: none;
}
```

note the absense of whitespace between the id and class since it is on the same element.

Comment: Why are you including the class in the selector? All that is doing is making the browser work harder, especially since there should only be one id on each page.

Comment: he is trying to override the default div background for a particular div. This target can be used for using a different image as background, (lets say)

Comment: All I'm saying is that your selector is overkill. And not only is it redundant, but it will actually slow the rendering of the document down due to the way CSS reads right to left. It won't be a noticeable difference, but why have the class at all when there is absolutely no need?

Answer (score 2):

In CSS children inherit properties from parents. You'll have to override the style of the parent in your child style declarations. In this case, since it is a background you are trying to override your .child style declaration will look like this:

```
.child {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

As the others above have pointed out you could also expand on the selector and write a new rule for the id attribute on the element:

```
 #tempDiv {
   background: none;
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using the class name in the bottom selector? It is not needed with an ID, and actually slows page rendering slightly.